# js grab class from modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list in my html that is built off of a `foreach` loop, and each item in the list has a link to a modal (built using a unique number in the `id` of the modal)

Regardless, the modal of each line pops up with the correct info, and I have a button where I'm trying to (upon button press) grab the `h2` class `campaign_id` and print the text there in the console. Currently it prints to the console but it prints the final value in the list every time, which is probably an issue with the `foreach`.

How can I grab and print to the console the H2 text of only the currently popped up modal?

```
    @foreach($getList as $campaign)
    <div id="expire_campaign_modal{{$campaign->campaign_id}}" class="uk-modal">
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="width:30%;">
            <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
            <div class="uk-grid">
                <div class="uk-width-1-1">
                    <div class="md-card">
                        <div class="md-card-content" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:baseline;">
                                <h2 class="campaign_id">{{$campaign->campaign_id}} - </h2>
                                <h2 style="margin-left: 10px;"> {{$campaign->campaign_name}}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Are you sure you want to expire this campaign?</h3>
                            <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary expire-campaign">Expire</button>
                            <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach

    $(".expire-campaign").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var campaign_id = document.querySelector(".campaign_id").textContent;

        console.log(campaign_id);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use *this* object to refer the currently clicked button. Then target the `closest()` element with class `md-card-content` to `find()` the expected element.

Change:

```
var campaign_id = document.querySelector(".campaign_id").textContent;
```

To:

```
var campaign_id = $(this).closest('.md-card-content').find(".campaign_id").text();
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".expire-campaign").click(function(e){
  console.clear();
  e.preventDefault();
  var campaign_id = $(this).closest('.md-card-content').find(".campaign_id").text();
  console.log(campaign_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expire_campaign_modal1" class="uk-modal">
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="width:30%;">
      <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
      <div class="uk-grid">
          <div class="uk-width-1-1">
              <div class="md-card">
                  <div class="md-card-content" style="text-align: center;">
                      <div style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:baseline;">
                          <h2 class="campaign_id">campaign->campaign_id -1 </h2>
                          <h2 style="margin-left: 10px;"> campaign->campaign_name 1</h2>
                      </div>
                      <h3>Are you sure you want to expire this campaign?</h3>
                      <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary expire-campaign">Expire</button>
                      <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="expire_campaign_modal2" class="uk-modal">
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="width:30%;">
      <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
      <div class="uk-grid">
          <div class="uk-width-1-1">
              <div class="md-card">
                  <div class="md-card-content" style="text-align: center;">
                      <div style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:baseline;">
                          <h2 class="campaign_id">campaign->campaign_id - 2</h2>
                          <h2 style="margin-left: 10px;"> campaign->campaign_name 2</h2>
                      </div>
                      <h3>Are you sure you want to expire this campaign?</h3>
                      <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary expire-campaign">Expire</button>
                      <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```